# Unsure of MySQL Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I've created this query -

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(`search_type`) AS `Count_Search`, `query` 
    FROM `bot_logging` 
    WHERE 
        `channel`='" . $input . "' 
    AND 
        `search_type`='price' 
    GROUP BY `query` 
    ORDER BY count(`search_type`) DESC;
```

It works flawlessly! It takes the input from the URL (since this a PHP Page) and does the query as desired - https://puu.sh/HeXkV.png

My question now is, how do I make a query in which I count the 'query' items and display that next to the channel name?

IE , this channel name is lvndmark and I want my results to be like so:

LVNDMARK | 363

TIA.

Comment: Without seeing what your table looks like this is my guess. `select channel, count(query) from bot_logging group by channel`

Comment: If by "perfectly" you mean "has a giant SQL injection hole" then your definition of perfect is different from mine.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: You should show at least a minimal representation of the schema you're working with. Normally this just calls for a `GROUP BY` on something different, like maybe `channel` in your case?

Comment: @bassxzero Welp, that was far simpler than I expected it to be. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman Who upset you? I simply said it works without error. Yes, it's not ideal, I know that, I'm clearly just getting started with MySQL if I'm asking such a base level question.

Comment: I'm being lightly sarcastic but also advising you that this code has a potentially catastrophic bug in it. It only appears to work. It's actually hiding a serious problem.

Comment: what is the relationship between channel and query?  you seem to show wanting to group by channel and produce a count, but what does it mean to "count the 'query' items"?  (bassxzero's suggestion will produce a count of how many rows for each channel had a non-null query)